# Functions inside for loops - how to do it right?

Tags: javascript

I am having a really hard time with functioning of javascript, and I will explain it with this piece of code (lets say `patients` size is 3):

```
for(j=0; j<patients.length; j++){
            console.log("before function - "+j);
            DButils.getDaysLeft(patients[j] , function(daysLeft){
                console.log("inside function - "+j);
            });
            console.log("end - "+j);
        }
```

This is the output I get:

```
before function - 0
end - 0
before function - 1
end - 1
before function - 2
end - 2
inside function - 3
inside function - 3
inside function - 3
```

because of that problem, if I do `patients[j]` inside the function it always gives me `undefined`, obviously because patients is only at the size of 3.

I understand that the function functioning as a thread and therefore the loop ends before we enter the callback of the function, but how do I solve it? what can I do to make it work as a normal 'for loop' like `c#` or `java` would work with that piece of code?

Comment: Welcome to JS. You must have been confused a lot. Make the `function(daysLeft){console.log("inside function - "+j)}` function definition an IIFE and save `j` under a closure. Like `(function(daysLeft){console.log("inside function - "+j)})(j);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> JavaScript have `function` level scope not `block` level scope.

Use `closure`, it remembers the value of a variable in which it is created.

Try this:

```js
for (j = 0; j < patients.length; j++) {
  console.log("before function - " + j);
  DButils.getDaysLeft(patients[j], (function(j) {
    return function(daysLeft) {
      console.log("inside function - " + j);
    }
  })(j));
  console.log("end - " + j);
}
```

Comment: Should I edit the "getDaysLeft" signature to make it work?

Comment: No..Closure returns inner function which will be your callback and it will be invoked later as your callback was working...

Comment: Thanks, it's working, I will mark as answer as soon as I can.